# FormIO FormBuilder not showing in Angular 8

Tags: angular, formio

I'm following the instructions https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/wiki/Form-Builder and I don't see any form-builder being rendered on my page, even though there is no client error.

Here is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nddjH.jpg
For some reason the form-builder is being rendered as 0x0.

My code:

**questionnaire-builder.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'questionnaire-builder',
  templateUrl: './questionnaire-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionnaire-builder.component.css']
})
export class QuestionnaireBuilderComponent{
  @ViewChild('json', {static: true}) jsonElement?: ElementRef;
  public form: Object = {components: []};

  onChange(event) {
    this.jsonElement.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
    this.jsonElement.nativeElement.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(event.form, null, 4)));
  }
}
```

**questionnaire-builder.component.html**

```
<p>Is form-builder working?</p>

<form-builder [form]="{
  components: []
}"></form-builder>


<form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)"></form-builder>
<div class="well jsonviewer">
  <pre id="json"><code class="language-json" #json></code></pre>
</div>
```

**questionnaire.module.ts**

```
...
import {FormioModule} from 'angular-formio';
import {MatFormioModule} from 'angular-material-formio';

import {QuestionnaireBuilderComponent} from './questionnaire-builder/questionnaire-builder.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    QuestionnaireBuilderComponent,
  ],
  exports: [],
  entryComponents: [
    QuestionnaireBuilderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
...
    MatFormioModule,
    FormioModule,
  ],
})
export class QuestionnaireModule {
}
```

Comment: can you tell me is there any javascript console errors you see?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the other `<form-builder>` template from your html.

Try this and see if anything renders.

```html
<form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)"></form-builder>
<div class="well jsonviewer">
  <pre id="json"><code class="language-json" #json></code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using both the MatFormioModule and FormioModule at the same time is ideal, i had to use either one of the two at the same time to be able to render my form and the form builder, try using one at a time, hope this help.